# EditText with some predefined choices

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` where use can enter any text.
At the same time the user is most likely to enter a predefined value from a certain array of texts.
What should be most elegant way to achieve this?

It's like a `EditComboBox` on web where they have `'Choice1', 'Choice2'..` and then `'Other...'` at the end, by pressing `Other` you can enter anything you want.

But in Android no such thing it seems

Has someone seen or implemented a screen like this?

Comment: perhaps you are looking for this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: It can be useful, but my user wouldn't know of the predefined choices he's most likely to enter before he sees them. Those predefined choices are likely to appeal to him but I don't think he could think of them beforehand (which would be required in case of AutoCompleteText)

Comment: AutoCompleteTextView uses an Adapter. As such, it can take its "vocabulary" from a table in a database (or a text file or whatever not "hardcoded"). The database could be fed by your user, who will insert the needed words from time to time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you can implement `AutoCompleteTextView`. If your user doesn't want to select from a drop down list, he can enter his own text there and you can get the text same as a normal `EditText`. This is working for me:

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(your_id_here);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, <your_predifined_list>);
autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If the user didn't selected the text from drop-down, you can get that text as:

```
String entry = autoComplete.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the AutoCompleteTextView as mentioned by upenpat.  More information and a brief example can be found at the Android Developers site:

[Providing Auto-complete Suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#AutoComplete)